# NAT (Internet connection sharing) switching between multiple public interfaces

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables, internet, connection-sharing

My Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) laptop has three network interfaces:

1. `eth0`: wired interface sometimes connected to the Internet
2. `wlan0`: wireless interface sometimes connected to the Internet
3. `vboxnet0`: wired interface (actually a VirtualBox virtual interface) connected to another computer (actually a VirtualBox virtual machine with networking in host-only mode)

I'd like to use `iptables` to set up NAT/IP masquerading to share whichever Internet connection is up (preferring the wired if both are up) with the other computer.

The following works when `eth0` is plugged in:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward &&
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE &&
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o vboxnet0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT &&
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

If I switch from wired to wireless, this obviously stops working.

I tried:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward &&
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o '!vboxnet0' -j MASQUERADE &&
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i '!vboxnet0' -o vboxnet0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT &&
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vboxnet0 -o '!vboxnet0' -j ACCEPT
```

but it did not work.  I could try to do some Network Manager scripts to change the `iptables` rules whenever an interfaces goes up or down, but I figured it would be possible without jumping through such hoops.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Simple

Here's a very simple `iptables` ruleset that masquerades everything. This one works for many simpler setups. It won't work if the box is working as a full-blown router — it has a potentially nasty habit of NATting *all* traffic that leaves your computer.

```bash
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -t nat -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o wlan+ -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

## Full

If the simple solution fails to work, or if your configuration is more complex, this ruleset might help:

```bash
NATIF='vboxnet+'
MARK=1
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i $NATIF -j MARK --set-mark $MARK
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -t nat -m mark --mark $MARK -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o wlan+ -t nat -m mark --mark $MARK -j MASQUERADE
```

It marks packets coming in through any `vboxnet*` interface, then, later, masquerades (SNAT) any packets going out of `eth*` or `wlan*` with the mark set.

## Also…

In addition to the `iptables` rules, you'll need to turn your host computer into a router by enabling packet forwarding. Put:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, then say

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf.
```

Alternatively:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4_ip_forward
```

The guest must also have a default route that gateways packets through the host's external interfaces (and for this, chances are host-only mode just won't work). Check its routing table (this depends on the guest OS).

Also, install `wireshark` or `tshark` and use them to examine packets. There's no better way to solve generic networking issues like this one.

Personally, I'd suggest changing the guest to use *bridged mode networking* and making available to it both of the host's interfaces. Then it can connect on its own, using the DHCP service on your router to get a local address on its own. No NAT needed.

Comment: I'll update it with the simpler solution, but I'd rather keep both if you don't mind. The mark-less (sic) method works fine for many simple configurations, but fails insidiously in more complex cases. This is how I first started using it, after all. :)

Comment: shouldn't `$MASK` be `$MARK`?